# Populate Textbox with Session Variable When Opening New Window

Tags: ajax, session-variables

I am attempting to populate a textbox in a new window with a Session variable from a parent window using an ajax call. When using Fiddler, I receive a 200 message, however, when ran from code, I'm getting a 500 Error.

I am aware that the ajax call is only returning an alert with the entire JSON result at this point because I haven't gotten to the step to actually pull the session variable yet.

Please offer any additional solutions to pull the Session variable from the parent window.

My JS from the parent is as follows:

```
function openRelatedItems(ReportID)
{
    window.open('../WebUserProvider/ReportLibraryView.aspx?r='+ ReportID,'mywin','left=50,top=50,location=no,resizable=yes, status=yes, scrollbars=no, titlebar=no, channelmode=no, directories=no');
    return false;
}
```

My JS from the window popup is as follows:

```
function callAjaxMethod() {
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "ReportLibraryView.aspx/GetSetSessionValue",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    var value = callAjaxMethod();
    var b;
});
```

My codebehind for the AJAX call is as follows:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
    public static string GetSetSessionValue()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["AppealNo"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So then, your working flow is as follow: 1) You open a popup pointing to `ReportLibraryView.aspx` ...that page has an ajax call that populate de textbox..correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Correct.  One note is that the ReportLibraryView.aspx that opens has a reportId as a parameter in the query string. Not sure if that matters if the ajax call is calling the GetSetSessionValue() webmethod directly from ReportLibraryView.aspx.cs.

Comment: Try: `url: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/pathToWebService/ReportLibraryView.aspx/GetSetSessionValue")%>",`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. The URL passed the string "<%=ResolveUrl('~/ReportLibraryView.aspx/GetSetSessionValue')%>‌​‌​" into the URL. I'm not sure why the server tags aren't working properly. the ajax call is not using the ResolveUrl() function, rather it is just being passed in as a string

Comment: ResolveUrl doesn't work if you have your javascript separated from the page....

Comment: I added the js to the <head> section of the ReportsLibraryView.aspx.  When I did, received a runtime error as follows: "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."